# A list of available D-Bus services

Tags: linux, d-bus, ipc

Is there such a thing as list of available D-Bus services?
I've stumbled upon a few, like those provided by NetworkManager, Rhythmbox, Skype, HAL.

I wonder if I can find a rather complete list of provided services/interfaces.

Comment: Similar question on ask Ubuntu site →[appmenu - How do I get a list of all of the available dbus properties? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147568/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-of-the-available-dbus-properties)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

On `QT` setups (short commands and clean, human readable output) you can run:

```
qdbus
```

will list list the services available on the session bus and

```
qdbus --system
```

will list list the services available on the system bus.

---

On any setup you can use `dbus-send`

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus  /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
```

Just like `qdbus`, if `--session` or no message bus is specified, `dbus` will send to the login session message bus. So the above will list the services available on the session bus.
Use `--system` if you want instead to use the system wide message bus:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus  /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
```

Comment: @don-crissti how to the to list all object-paths under a service with `dbus-send` or `gdbus`?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam - I have added an answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203678).

Comment: DFeet has been discontinued but there's an alternative called [D-Spy](https://apps.gnome.org/Dspy/).

Comment: @DavidFerenczyRogožan - you should put that in an answer (with a couple of screenshots maybe...). I haven't been using gnome in years, I'll remove the D-Feet reference from my answer.

Comment: Note that you can also use qdbus to list possible paths, for example `qdbus org.xfce.Thunar`; and you can also list methods for given service and path, for example `qdbus org.xfce.Thunar /org/xfce/FileManager`.

Comment: For modern systems using `systemd` you want to use `busctl`.

Answer (score 48):

With Python it can be simpler.

System services:

```
import dbus
for service in dbus.SystemBus().list_names():
    print(service)
```

Session services:

```
import dbus
for service in dbus.SessionBus().list_names():
    print(service)
```

Comment: Upvoted. I asked a follow-up question to your answer.
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203410/how-to-list-all-object-paths-under-a-dbus-service

Comment: I have a question, in a Plasma 5 desktop environment, the service __org.kde.Spectacle__ is used for taking screenshot (and it's working), but it is neither listed in system bus nor session bus, why is that?

Comment: To help those who may be looking: for at least python 2.7.13 and 3.6, the package needed for this is [dbus-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbus-python/), installable with `pip install dbus-python`. The python-dbus package is also available (I was unable to get in working in the 2 minutes I tried).

Comment: This solution was very helpful on an embedded system that didn't have qdbus installed.

Answer (score 35):

`qdbusviewer` is your best friend; it allows you to send D-bus messages as well:

[image: qdbusviewer showing the Session Bus tab with three subpanels]

Comment: Seems broken as of 2014. It lists the services but can't send messages..

Comment: I can't even start it on Ubuntu 14.04. It fails with: `qdbusviewer: could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qdbusviewer': No such file or directory`

Comment: @Pithikos `d-feet` works as of today.

Comment: @sherrellbc Please consider adding `d-feet` as an answer to make it more visible

Comment: As of Ubuntu 20.04, runs but doesn't list all services

Comment: I wonder what are these :1.1* services...

Comment: @kasperd I need to install `qttools5-dev-tools` to avoid that error on Debian 11.

Comment: Seems broken with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. All I get is `qdbusviewer: could not find a Qt installation of ''`

Answer (score 21):

[`gdbus`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus.html) is part of glib2 and supports Bash completions. Here is how to use it (on Fedora):

```
bash-4.4$ source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gdbus
bash-4.4$ gdbus call --system --dest <TAB><TAB>
```

This will show all possible destinations. To get a list of the available interfaces DBus exports the `org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames` method. You can call it by running:

```
gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.DBus \
           --object-path /org/freedesktop/DBus  \
           --method org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
```

Unfortunately this leads to unreadable output. Fortunately the output is valid python, so this is possible:

```
gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.DBus      \
           --object-path /org/freedesktop/DBus       \
           --method org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames | \
    python -c 'import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(eval(sys.stdin.read()))'
```

I don't usually do this, but is a nice trick to keep on sleeve. I use `gdbus` for introspecting and proving concepts before moving to code. The bash completion saves a lot of typing and avoid typos. Would be nice to have `gdbus` displaying a nicer output.

Comment: Neat tool recommendation; thanks! As of F31 at least note that Bash completions are loaded by default, no need to source them manually.

Answer (score 15):

I prefer [`busctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/busctl.html).
Note that unlike other tools like `qdbus` and `dbus-send` this one defaults to the `--system` bus so to communicate with the session manager you have to explicitly use the `--user` switch. Also, the `list` command is the default operation if no command is specified so

```
busctl
```

is the same as

```
busctl list --system
```

or

```
# busctl list
NAME                                             PID PROCESS         USER             CONNECTION    UNIT                                                               SESSION DESCRIPTION
:1.0                                             162 systemd-timesyn systemd-timesync :1.0          systemd-timesyncd.service                                          -       -          
:1.1                                             157 systemd-network systemd-network  :1.1          systemd-networkd.service                                           -       -          
:1.10                                            199 phosphor-dump-m root             :1.10         obmc-dump-monitor.service                                          -       -          
:1.11                                            216 fru-device      root             :1.11         xyz.openbmc_project.FruDevice.service         
...
```

and after you can see the tree for each one

```
# busctl tree :1.0
`-/org
  `-/org/freedesktop
    |-/org/freedesktop/LogControl1
    `-/org/freedesktop/timesync1
```

Comment: `busctl` is definitely the way to go for all distros that default to `systemd`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend also [`dasbus`](https://github.com/rhinstaller/dasbus)

```
from dasbus.connection import SystemMessageBus

bus = SystemMessageBus()
busproxy = bus.proxy
for i in sorted(busproxy.ListNames()):
    print(i)
```

(Substitute `SessionMessageBus` for the session bus.)

From the shell, on systemd systems there is [`busctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/busctl.html)

```
busctl list
```