# How to list all object paths under a dbus service?

Tags: python, d-bus, ipc

This is a follow-up question to [A list of available DBus services](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46301/a-list-of-available-dbus-services).

The following python code will list all available DBus services.

```
import dbus
for service in dbus.SystemBus().list_names():
    print(service)
```

How do we list out the object paths under the services in python? It is ok if the answer does not involve python although it is preferred.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It is ok if the answer does not involve python although it is preferred.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`QT` setups provide the most convenient way to do it, via `qdbus`:

```
qdbus --system org.freedesktop.UPower
```

prints

```
/
/org
/org/freedesktop
/org/freedesktop/UPower
/org/freedesktop/UPower/Wakeups
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ADP0
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

---

As to the python way... per the official [docs](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces) (under *standard interfaces*):

> There are some standard interfaces that may be useful across various
>   D-Bus applications.
>
> **org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable**
>
> This interface has one method:
>
> ```
> org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect (out STRING xml_data)
> ```
>
> Objects instances may implement `Introspect` which returns an *XML*
>   description of the object, including its interfaces (with signals and
>   methods), objects below it in the object path tree, and its
>   properties.

So here's a very simplistic example that should get you started. It uses [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and [`dbus`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import dbus
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def rec_intro(bus, service, object_path):
    print(object_path)
    obj = bus.get_object(service, object_path)
    iface = dbus.Interface(obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable')
    xml_string = iface.Introspect()
    for child in ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string):
        if child.tag == 'node':
            if object_path == '/':
                object_path = ''
            new_path = '/'.join((object_path, child.attrib['name']))
            rec_intro(bus, service, new_path)

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
rec_intro(bus, 'org.freedesktop.UPower', '/org/freedesktop/UPower')
```

It recursively introspects `org.freedesktop.UPower` starting from e.g. `/org/freedesktop/UPower` and prints all object paths (node names):

```
/org/freedesktop/UPower
/org/freedesktop/UPower/Wakeups
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ADP0
```

which is pretty much what you'd get if you used `d-feet` (not that you'd need it):

[image]

Comment: How do I create a list of object paths from `rec_intro(bus, 'org.freedesktop.UPower', '/org/freedesktop/UPower')` ?

Comment: No, I mean creating a python list of object paths, so that I can check (in my script) if particular object-path exists in the list. It prints the objectpath alright., But I want something like `k =  rec_intro(bus, 'org.freedesktop.UPower', '/org/freedesktop/UPower')`. I suppose it is possible by modifying the function little bit.

Comment: Example code with qbus: ```bus = dbus.SessionBus().....
obj_path = '/org/gnome/Gnote/RemoteControl'..........
cmd = 'qdbus org.gnome.Gnote'.........
while obj_path not in ((subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)).decode("utf-8")).split("\n"):
    ........pass```

Comment: @KhurshidAlam - initialize a list before the function e.g. `mylist=[]` then replace `print` with `mylist.append` and then as the last command in that function block `return mylist` - that's pretty much what there is... you can then  iterate over the list or whatever e.g. add at the bottom of the script `for x in mylist:
    print("OBJ_PATH", x)` to have them printed with a `OBJ_PATH` prefix...

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure you can do this programmatically in Python. You might but it will be a huge headache to figure out how. I tried to do it before and ended up hating Dbus. Anyhow I recommend to use [d-feet](http://live.gnome.org/DFeet) if you want to investigate things. Below is a screenshot that I stole from my [blog](https://linuxmeerkat.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/python-detection-of-usb-storage-device/).

[image]

Once you know the program name, object path, etc. you can then use Python to access those things.

**Example**

```
progname = 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager'
objpath  = '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager'
intfname = 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager'
methname = 'GetDevices'

bus = dbus.SystemBus()

obj = bus.get_object(progname, objpath)
interface = dbus.Interface(obj, intfname)     # Get the interface to obj
method = interface.get_dbus_method(methname)  # The method on that interface

method()                                      # And finally calling the method
```

As you see, it's a pain in the ass to get a simple thing done. But this is the easiest workflow you can get with Dbus!

So use a GUI tool to find out the object paths, interfaces, etc. Then use the code snippet above as a template to access those things. Also I suggest you do this via IPython's interpreter to see what methods, properties, etc. each object has (by hitting tab).

Comment: `d-feet` is missing `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power` which I was looking to inspect. I'm feeling kind of defeated :(

Comment: Perhaps you meant: `intf.get_dbus_method...`

Answer (score 4):

If the service has an object implementing `org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager`, its method `GetManagedObjects` returns [“all objects, interfaces and properties in a single method call.”](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-objectmanager) For example, UDisks2 has such an object.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way using Python and GDBus.
The `python-dbus` module is I believe being deprecated (very slowly), and its not the best API. There are a few other promising projects for Python which can be found by googling.

For the Gtk/GLib/GObject world, the simplest is to use GDBus which is built in to [`Gio`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0) library (which comes with `GLib`). This is the recommended way for new Gtk-based code (rather than `dbus` module). If you are writing a Gtk app or trying to script a Gtk-based desktop environment (Gnome, Xfce, Cinnamon, Mate, Pantheon etc.), these libraries are probably already available. You can use in Python through Gobject Introspection (python `gi` module). [Python gi API Docs here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/main.html).

Here is an example introspect function which returns a single [`DBusNodeInfo`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/DBusNodeInfo.html).

```
from gi.repository import Gio, GLib


def introspect(bus, name, object_path):
    res = bus.call_sync(
        name,  # bus_name
        object_path,  # object_path
        'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable',  # interface_name
        'Introspect',  # method_name
        None,  # parameters
        GLib.VariantType("(s)"),  # reply_type
        Gio.DBusCallFlags.NONE,  # flags
        -1,  # timeout_msecs
        None  # cancellable
    )

    if not res:
        return None

    return Gio.DBusNodeInfo.new_for_xml(res[0])
```

(API docs link: [Gio.DBusConnection.call_sync](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/DBusConnection.html#Gio.DBusConnection.call_sync).)

Note that you will need to get the bus doing something like

```
bus = Gio.bus_get_sync(Gio.BusType.SYSTEM)
```

or

```
bus = Gio.bus_get_sync(Gio.BusType.SESSION)
```

(See [`Gio.bus_get_sync`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/functions.html#Gio.bus_get_sync) docs)

`DBusNodeInfo` has `nodes`, `interfaces` and `path` properties. The `path` property contains just the last segment of the actual path (e.g. "bar", not "/foo/bar"). `nodes` is a list of `DBusNodeInfo`, but note that these are not recursively introspected, you must iterate over them, build the absolute path by joining to the parent path with a slash, and call `introspect` again.

As you can see, the library includes XML parser and parse tree API, unlike python-dbus, so there is no need to use Python's `xml.etree` etc.

### Recursive introspection

Building on the above `introspect` function you could do something like (Python 3 code):

```
def introspect_tree(bus, name, object_path):
    node = introspect(bus, name, object_path)

    if node:
        yield object_path, node

        if object_path == '/':
            object_path = ''

        for child in node.nodes:
            yield from introspect_tree(bus, name, f"{object_path}/{child.path}")
```

This is a generator of `(object_path, node)` pairs, where `object_path` is the absolute path and `node` is the `DBusNodeInfo` object.

If you just the want paths:

```
bus = Gio.bus_get_sync(Gio.BusType.SYSTEM)
for path, node in introspect_tree(bus, 'org.freedesktop.UPower', '/org/freedesktop/UPower'):
    print(path)
```

Prints:

```
/org/freedesktop/UPower
/org/freedesktop/UPower/Wakeups
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ADP0
```

### Introspecting interfaces

The `interfaces` property of `DBusNodeInfo` objects contains a list of [`Gio.DBusInterfaceInfo`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/DBusInterfaceInfo.html#Gio.DBusInterfaceInfo) objects of the interfaces the object has. From there, you have `name`, `methods`, `properties` and `signals` properties.

### Asynchronous API

Note that the above code is all synchronous, which is fine for command line apps and simple tools. However, there is also an asynchronous API which you will definitely want to use for GUI apps. All the functions that end with `_sync` have async versions e.g. `call_sync` has [`call`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/DBusConnection.html#Gio.DBusConnection.call) and [`call_finish`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/DBusConnection.html#Gio.DBusConnection.call_finish). There's also support for timeouts and cancellation (see `timeout_msec` and `cancellable` parameters of `call`/`call_sync` for example). Pretty easy to use once you figure it out, can be hard to find the docs though. Reading existing source code is a good way, especially the [`d-feet` app source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/d-feet/-/blob/master/src/dfeet/introspection.py) which demonstrates asynchronous use of the APIs mentioned here.

### `gdbus` CLI tool

Another fantastic part of GDBus is the [`gdbus` command line tool](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/gdbus.html) which comes with the library (should be available in your Gtk-based desktop environments). Like `qdbus` (mentioned above), it has tab completion and excellent introspection functionality built in and is very useful for quick exploration and discovering names and paths.

Try:

```bsh
gdbus introspect -r --system --dest org.freedesktop.UPower --object-path /org/freedesktop/UPower
```

Answer (score 2):

What I know from my experience to get the object paths of a bus name (service) it is possible to introspect with object path '/' i.e. (using the above example)

```
introspectfunc('org.freedesktop.UPower', '/')
```

this should return:

```
<node name="/"> 
<node name="org"/>
<node name="org"/>
<node name="org"/>
<node name="org"/>
<node name="org"/>
<node name="org"/></node>
```

then introspect with path '/org'

```
introspectfunc('org.freedesktop.UPower', '/org')
```

this should return:

```
<node name="/org"> 
<node name="freedesktop"/>
<node name="freedesktop"/>
<node name="freedesktop"/>
<node name="freedesktop"/>
<node name="freedesktop"/>
<node name="freedesktop"/></node>
```

and so on:

```
introspectfunc('org.freedesktop.UPower', '/org/freedesktop')
introspectfunc('org.freedesktop.UPower', '/org/freedesktop/UPower')
etc.
```

It is like going through the folder structure of the hard drive where the object path '/' is the root and every node is subfolder.
This seems the best way to retrieve the object paths of a particular bus name (service) and to construct a collection containing the object paths

Answer (score 2):

As per [#don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203410/how-to-list-all-object-paths-under-a-dbus-service#203678) answers, I implemented, This solution gives to interface name and method and signals information

```python
import dbus
from xml.etree import ElementTree
bus = dbus.SystemBus()

def busNames():
    return [ name for name in  bus.list_names() if not name.startswith(":") ]


def pathNames(service,object_path="/",paths=None,serviceDict=None):
    if paths == None:
        paths = {}
    paths[object_path] = {}
    obj = bus.get_object(service, object_path)
    iface = dbus.Interface(obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable')
    xml_string = iface.Introspect()
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)
    for child in root:
        if child.tag == 'node':
            if object_path == '/':
                    object_path = ''
            new_path = '/'.join((object_path, child.attrib['name']))
            pathNames(service, new_path,paths)
        else:
            if object_path == "":
                object_path = "/"
            functiondict = {}
            paths[object_path][child.attrib["name"]] = functiondict
            for func in child.getchildren():
                if func.tag not in functiondict.keys():
                    functiondict[func.tag] =[]
                functiondict[func.tag].append(func.attrib["name"])
    if serviceDict == None:
        serviceDict = {}
    serviceDict[service] = paths
    return serviceDict



import json
import random
service=random.sample(busNames(),1).pop()
print service
print json.dumps(pathNames(service),indent=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

### python with `dasbus`

With [`dasbus`](https://github.com/rhinstaller/dasbus) I wrote this POC:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree

from dasbus.connection import SystemMessageBus
from dasbus.error import DBusError


def tree(bus, bus_name, path=None):
    obj = bus.get_proxy(bus_name, path or "/")
    try:
        xml = obj.Introspect()
    except DBusError as exc:
        # implement here your exception handling
        raise Exception(str(exc))
    if path:
        yield path
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(xml)
    for node in root.findall("node[@name]"):
        yield from tree(bus, bus_name, (path or "") + "/" + node.attrib["name"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bus = SystemMessageBus()
    for pth in tree(bus, "org.freedesktop.login1"):
        print(pth)
```

which outputs

```
/org
/org/freedesktop
/org/freedesktop/LogControl1
/org/freedesktop/login1
/org/freedesktop/login1/user
/org/freedesktop/login1/user/_1000
/org/freedesktop/login1/user/self
/org/freedesktop/login1/session
/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_326
/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_324
/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_327
/org/freedesktop/login1/session/self
/org/freedesktop/login1/session/auto
/org/freedesktop/login1/seat
/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0
```

### shell with `busctl`

From the shell, with `systemd` [`busctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/busctl.html) you can use the `tree` command:

```
$ busctl tree org.freedesktop.login1
└─/org
  └─/org/freedesktop
    ├─/org/freedesktop/LogControl1
    └─/org/freedesktop/login1
      ├─/org/freedesktop/login1/seat
      │ └─/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0
      ├─/org/freedesktop/login1/session
      │ ├─/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_324
      │ ├─/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_326
      │ ├─/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_327
      │ ├─/org/freedesktop/login1/session/auto
      │ └─/org/freedesktop/login1/session/self
      └─/org/freedesktop/login1/user
        ├─/org/freedesktop/login1/user/_1000
        └─/org/freedesktop/login1/user/self
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the partly complete answer of [Reegan Miranda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526210/154557) I ported
the code to python 3.9 and made it introspect the whole bus system by regex filter.

```
#!/bin/python
#> usage: ./query-dbus.py --pattern "^.*activit.*$"
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='query dbus tree')
parser.add_argument('-s','--system', help='query SystemBus', required=False, default=False)
parser.add_argument('-S','--session', help='query SessionBus (default)', required=False, default=True)
parser.add_argument('-p','--pattern', help='search pattern', required=False, default=None)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

import re
pattern = None
if args['pattern']:
  pattern = re.compile(args['pattern'], re.IGNORECASE)

import dbus
from xml.etree import ElementTree

if args['session']:
  bus = dbus.SessionBus()
else:
  bus = dbus.SystemBus()

def busNames():
    return [ name for name in  bus.list_names() if not name.startswith(":") ]


def objectTree(service, object_path="/", paths=None, serviceDict=None):
    if str(service).startswith(':') == True: 
        return
      
    if paths == None:
        paths = {}
    pathdict = {}
    try:
      try:
          obj = bus.get_object(service, object_path)
      except dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
          print("[ERROR] service \"%s\" doesn't exist or isn't running" \
                % service)
          return
      
      try:
        iface = dbus.Interface(obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable')
        xml_string = iface.Introspect()
      except dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
        print("[ERROR] service \"%s\" doesn't reply request. timeout." \
                % service)
        return
      root = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)
      for child in root:
          if child.tag == 'node':
              if object_path == '/':
                      object_path = ''
              new_path = '/'.join((object_path, child.attrib['name']))
              objectTree(service, new_path, paths)
          else:
              if object_path == "":
                  object_path = "/"
              functiondict = {}
            
              for func in child:
                if pattern is None or pattern.match(func.attrib["name"]):
                  if func.tag not in functiondict.keys():
                      functiondict[func.tag] = []
                  functiondict[func.tag].append(func.attrib["name"])
                  
              if functiondict:
                pathdict[child.attrib["name"]] = functiondict
      if serviceDict == None:
          serviceDict = {}
      if pathdict:
        paths[object_path] = pathdict
      if paths:
        serviceDict[service] = paths
      return serviceDict
    except:
      raise

import json
import random

for service in bus.list_names():
  object_tree = objectTree(service)
  if object_tree:
    print(json.dumps(object_tree,indent=3))
```