# How to list all object paths under a dbus service only usign dbus command-line utility?

Tags: d-bus, ipc

How can I list the object path under a dbus services using ONLY `dbus-send` command line utility?

For now, I can only list services:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --type=method_call --print-reply  /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
```

or interfaces:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --type=method_call --print-reply /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect
```

This question is very similar to:

[How to list all object paths under a dbus service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203410/how-to-list-all-object-paths-under-a-dbus-service)

but it requires to use some utilities that are not available to me.

I use a closed embedded system and I cannot install anything, so I cannot use any of the following utilities:

- qdbusviewer
- qdbus
- d-feet
- python

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GetManagedObjects` method on the `org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager` interface. But that won't print just list of paths but dump the entire object so you'd need to parse the paths from the outputted dictionary.

If `busctl` (from systemd) is an option for you, I'd recommend using it because it has JSON output so you can parse it with `jq`. Example for UDisks2 JSON dump:

```
# busctl call org.freedesktop.UDisks2 /org/freedesktop/UDisks2 org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager GetManagedObjects --json=short | jq ".data[0] | keys[]"
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/Manager"
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda"
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda1"
...
```

With `dbus-send` the call would look like

```
# dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.UDisks2 --type=method_call --print-reply  /org/freedesktop/UDisks2 org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects
```

but you need to parse the output manually.

Edit: For `org.bluez` the commands are:

```
# busctl call org.bluez / org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager GetManagedObjects --json pretty | jq ".data[0] | keys[]"
"/org/bluez"
"/org/bluez/hci0"
"/org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_1B_66_C1_56_01"
```

and

```
# dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --type=method_call --print-reply  / org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObject
```

and you can try something like

```
# dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --type=method_call --print-reply  / org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects | grep -A 1 "dict entry" | grep "object path" | cut -d"\"" -f2
/org/bluez
/org/bluez/hci0
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_1B_66_C1_56_01
```

for parsing the output to get just the object paths.

Comment: Unfortunately busctl is not an option

Comment: The other command that you suggested gives the following result: Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 was not provided by any .service files

Comment: I can do something like this for bluez:

dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --type=method_call --print-reply / org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects

but unfortunately doesn't work for bluealsa (the service I need to get object paths from) because the interface is missing

Comment: I've update my answer with `dbus-send` command working with bluez. Something more advanced for parsing the output than `grep | grep | cut` would be probably better but I was never good with `awk` and/or `sed`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it is not bluez the problem. I can manage bluez. It is bluealsa that I cannot investigate (https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa). The latter is the bridge services between the bluetooth stack and alsa. Bluealsa does not have a ObjectManager interface, so I cannot call the GetManagedObjects method.

Comment: The interfaces available are: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties, org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable and org.bluealsa.Manager1 and none of these seems to me useful at getting the object paths.